# create web push notification(not for android app, but for website only)?

Tags: javascript, php

I have gone through so many web pages but unable to find proper answer, can you help me with it. I want to know how one can create web push notification(not for android app, but for website only)??

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this line of code:

```
var myNotification = new Notification(title, options);
```

I give you a better example, you have to ask to the user if you can add notifications:

```
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    console.log("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have alredy been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied' || Notification.permission === "default") {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
```

You may consult the [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification) and the [MDN's specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification).

Comment: Thank you S.P.H.I.N.X...... how to get client's ID so that i can send him notification next time

Comment: I do not know what is client's ID but you can use localStorage to get an ID in the user's computer.